# Algorithm to fit windows on desktop (like tile)

Tags: algorithm, packing, tiling

I searching algorithm to solve problem like this:

I have few windows, each window can be moved and re sized but with specified ratio between width and height, eg. 2:1 (height:width).

Each window can't be on other window and all windows must be fully visible.
Free area (desktop wallpaper visibility) must be minimal.

Can anyone tell me what algorithm i need for this type of problem?

Greetings,

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810550/position-boxes-like-in-expose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436043/expose-layout-algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889229/the-logic-behind-macoss-expose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach, which might be simpler to implement than packing, would be to subdivide your screen size into the required number of panes, then fit a window which satisfies your other requirements inside the pane.  Since you'll probably have a small number of windows open at any time, and since your screen doesn't change its size dynamically, you can probably pre-compute all the arrangements you need for 1 up to O(100) open windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you can relax the requirement that all windows have a given "aspect ratio" then the problem becomes very simple. Suppose you have `N` "tiles" to arrange on a single screen, then these can be arranged in columns where the number of columns, `NumCols` is the square root of `N` rounded up when `N` is not a perfect square. All columns of tiles are of equal width. The number of tiles in each column is then `N/NumCols` rounded either up or down as necessary to make the total number of columns be `N`. This is what Microsoft Excel does under View > Arrange All > Tiled. Excel chooses to put the columns with one fewer tiles on the left of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to treat it as a [2D packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), like the 1D bin packing problem. There's a sample algorithm posted [here](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=392413), for example, with some good references.

Comment: What with window resizing feature?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is relayout -- the layout algorithm is what you're after isn't it, not the infrastructure around it?